# How does Jedis library work under the hood?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I've had to use the Jedis library recently and it's a nifty library. I know Redis is written in C, does Jedis just wrap Java around C?
Couldn't figure it out by just looking at the Jedis source code.
Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 6):

Jedis is a native Java client library, it does not wrap a C library to 
connect to Redis, instead it implements the [Redis Protocol](https://redis.io/topics/protocol) in Java.  See the [Protocol.java](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/Protocol.java) file for most of the implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

Jedis is a client library. It accesses the Redis server which is written in C over the network. There's no need to wrap anything. Since there is a public API, you can write clients in any kinds of languages.

The same applies to any product that provides a public API and network access.